# Sed is not Interpreting Pipes Correctly

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, sed, pipe

OK, this is hard to explain, so I will give a reproducible example:

I have a text file `test.txt` contains the line:

```
somesetting-parameter /an/old/path
```

I want to replace it with a path I can get via `ls`, for example:

```
ls /etc/init.d/ssh*
```

which outputs either `/etc/init.d/ssh` (Debian) or `/etc/init.d/sshd` (others)

Now to replace it I wanted to use `sed`, and use the back-quotes feature, so i ran the command:

```
sed -i "s/\/an\/old\/path/`ls /etc/init.d/ssh* | sed 's/\//\\\//g'`/" test.txt
```

but it's giving me the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

while the (sub) command `ls /etc/init.d/ssh* | sed 's/\//\\\//g'` is giving the appropriate output

```
\/etc\/init.d\/ssh
```

piping is for the outer command to parse slashes appropriately.

**NOTE:**

I know that it's easily doable by a shell script simply by using a variable, but i asked this to know what is wrong, not to find an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the double quote data will still be processed by the shell, removing the backslash before it reach the sed...

Instead try single quotes, or double up on the back slashes inside the double quotes.

Comment: I doubled the backslash in the internal sed command like
`sed 's/\//\\\\\//g'` and it worked, many thanks.